# How to delete ALL value from a Column in SQLite with a single click?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want a button that deletes all the values inside a column with a single button click.

I know the code to delete the row or table but not all the values in it. Is it possible or do I have to delete the column and re-add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should be working:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(<COLUMN_NAME>, (String) null);
database.update(<TABLE_NAME>, values, null, null);
```

`<COLUMN_NAME>`, and `<TABLE_NAME>` are Strings, containing the column you want to clear and table name :)

Also, you can assign not only `null` value to `<COLUMN_NAME>`, but any other value you want. I.e.: `0`, or `""` (empty string), depending on your needs.

Comment: Nope, it does shows errors in `put` it says it gotta be (String, String)

Comment: It worked but complicated a lot my database because i've read that NONE column/row cant be changed to NULL it should be changed to 0 or "" (ZERO or BLANK) but not null.